# Documenting in grails

Tags: grails, documentation

I want to generate something like http://grails.org/doc/latest/ for my grails project.

I have tried grails doc, but It doesn't organize the project in Taglibs, etc.

I want something to fetch easily the taglib for a given namespace.

Also to see more clearly the global state of documentation of the project.

Do you know if exists a plugin for this or any workaround?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing that I know of that automatically generates this. Everything under src/docs/guide is included in the main documentation, and files under src/docs/ref are included in the left frame. Subdirectories under src/docs/ref create subsections.

See the Grails doc source folder structure at http://github.com/grails/grails-doc/tree/master/src/ for how the main docs work, and my plugin doc source at http://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/master/src/docs/ for a smaller example, which generates http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Answer (score 1):

I have recently contributed a plugin "Grails Runtime Docs" ( http://grails.org/plugin/grails-runtime-docs) to grails which is Grails aware. It organizes the grails artifacts and categorize the classes into Controllers, Commands, Domains, Services and Tag Libraries. The plugin generates groovy documentation from runtime so as to include the dynamic methods also, adding "Dynamic Method Summary" & "Dynamic Method Detail" in the generated html docs, that provide their source information.